# Creating an infinite loop in minesweeper function

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a cli-based minesweeper game in JavaScript. 

In a game of minesweeper, when you click on an empty square, all the adjacent empty squares are exposed as well as the numbered squares adjacent to those empty squares. 
I'm trying to mimic this functionality in my game, but the problem is this: the 3 functions that control this behavior (one of which is recursive) is creating an infinite loop, and I'm not totally sure why.

So here's how it works:

`createBoard()` generates a 10x10 game board with 10 mines in random places. `assignNumbers()` takes in the output of `createBoard()`, and assigns numbers to each "cell"; this number denotes the number of mines in adjacent cells.

The output of these two function looks like this: 
[image]

Because I don't want to the player to know the location of the mines, I've created a parallel game board (`playerBoard`) that doesn't show the location of mines, and which is updated on every turn using `updatePlayerBoard`.

So here's where the recursive stuff comes in:

`getCoordinates` takes in two numbers between 0 and 9  from the user that represent a coordinate on the gameboard. For example, it could be something like `[0,5]`, which represent x-axis and y-axis values, respectively. 
These values are then plugged into a function called `play`, which controls most of the game logic: 
-If the player's coordinates match with a bomb, game is ended 
-If the coordinates match a number, the equivalent square on `playerBoard` is converted to that number
-If coordinates hit an empty square (ie, a square with a zero value), the `checkSquares` function is executed.

`checkSquares` then looks at all 8 adjacent squares, and passes their coordinates to `play` for evaluation. 
So you end up with a loop between `checkSquares` and `play` until all clear cells or numbered cells have been exposed.

`checkSquares` in the following form works (when only checking the cell to the left):

```
const checkSquares = (x,y,board) => {

  const isRightEdge = y/9 ===1

    if(y>0 ){
      const coords = [x, y-1]
      play(coords[0],coords[1],board)
     }

   console.log(playerBoard)
}
```

However, when I try to check the cell to the right too, an infinite loop is created and the app crashes:

```
const checkSquares = (x,y,board) => {


    if(y>0 ){
      const coords = [x, y-1]
      play(coords[0],coords[1],board)
     }

     if(y<9){
       const coords = [x, y+1]
       play(coords[0],coords[1], board)
     }

   console.log(playerBoard)
}
```

Any suggestions as to why?

Here's the whole project:

***index.js***

```
import { board,playerBoard } from './createBoard.js'
import inquirer from 'inquirer'


const assignNumbers =  () => {
  for(let i = 0; i<board.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j<board[i].length; j++){
      if(board[i][j].toString() === 'x'){
       
        let newTotal = 0
        const isRightEdge = [j]/9 === 1
        const isLeftEdge = [j] === 0
         //check square to right
        if(!isRightEdge  && board[i][j+1].toString() === '') newTotal++
        //check square to left
        if([j]>0 && board[i][j-1].toString() === '') newTotal++
        //check square to north-west
        if([j]>0 && [i]>0 && board[i-1][j-1].toString() === '') newTotal++
        //check square to north-east
        if(!isRightEdge && [i]>0 && board[i-1][j+1].toString() === '') newTotal++
        //check square to south-west
        if([j]>0 && [i]<9 && board[i+1][j-1].toString() === '') newTotal++
        //check square to south-east
        if(!isRightEdge && [i]<9 && board[i+1][j+1].toString() === '') newTotal++
        //check square to north
        if([i]>0 && board[i-1][j].toString() === '') newTotal++
        //check square to the south
        if([i]<9 && board[i+1][j].toString() === '') newTotal++
        board[i][j] = newTotal
      }
    }
  }

}

assignNumbers()


const updatePlayerBoard = (x, y, type) => {
  if (type === "hit") {
    playerBoard[x][y] = "";
  } else if (type === "number-square") {
    playerBoard[x][y] = board[x][y].toString();
    console.log(playerBoard);
    getCoordinates();
  } else if (type === "blank-square"){
    playerBoard[x][y] = '⬛'
  }
};

const checkSquares = (x,y,board) => {


    if(y>0 ){
      const coords = [x, y-1]
      play(coords[0],coords[1],board)
     }

     if(y<9){
       const coords = [x, y+1]
       play(coords[0],coords[1], board)
     }

   console.log(playerBoard)
}

const play = (x, y, board) => {
  const resultType = ["hit", "number-square", "blank-square"];
  if (board[x][y].toString() === "") {
    updatePlayerBoard(x, y, resultType[0]);
    console.log("Game over!");
    process.exit(1);
  } else if (board[x][y] !== 0 && board[x][y].toString !== "") {
    updatePlayerBoard(x, y, resultType[1]);
  } else if(board[x][y] === 0){
    updatePlayerBoard(x, y, resultType[2]);
    checkSquares(x,y,board)
  }
};


const getCoordinates = async () => {
  const question = [
    {
      type: "input",
      name: "x-coordinate",
      message:
        "Please enter the first of two coordinates (any number from 0 up to 9)",
    },
    {
      type: "input",
      name: "y-coordinate",
      message: "Please enter the last coordinate (any number from 0 up to 9)",
    },
  ];
  let xCoordinate;
  let yCoordinate;

  inquirer.prompt(question).then((answers) => {
    xCoordinate = answers["x-coordinate"];
    yCoordinate = answers["y-coordinate"];

    play(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, board);
  });
};

console.log(board)
await getCoordinates()
```

***createBoard.js***

```
const randomNumbers = () => {
    var nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
      ranNums = [],
      i = nums.length,
      j = 0;
  
    while (i--) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      ranNums.push(nums[j]);
      nums.splice(j, 1);
    }
    return ranNums;
  };
  
  
  const getCoordinates = () => {
    const x = randomNumbers();
    const y = randomNumbers();
  
    let coordinates = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      let coordinate = [x[i], y[i]];
      coordinates.push(coordinate);
    }
  
    return coordinates;
  };
  
  const coordinates = getCoordinates()
  
  
  const createBoard = () => {
    let board = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      board[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        board[i][j] = ["x"];
      }
    }
  
    for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
      let x = coordinates[i][0];
      let y = coordinates[i][1];
      board[x][y] = [''];
    }
    return board
  };

  const createPlayerBoard = () => {
    let playerBoard = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      playerBoard[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        playerBoard[i][j] = '⬜';
      }
    }
    return playerBoard
  }

  export const board = createBoard()
  export const playerBoard = createPlayerBoard()
```

Comment: Have you tried do `else if` check on right, so it would be only one step per function call?

Comment: Are you sure that your exit condition in checkSquares should not also check for equals to  or >=?

Comment: In your `play` function, you are missing to check if the cell is already revealed. You are infinitely recurring on revealed cells.

Comment: your data representation is not suitable for this problem and using a recursive loop is not a good idea for this kind of processing